# Decimal to Binary C

Tags: c, unix

I have to write a C program that converts decimal to binary using numbers between 0 to 255. using 3 functions and no global variables. When I get it to run it just prints all zeros for some reason. This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getNumber();
int dectoBin(int, int binarray[], int);
void printBin(int binary[], int dec);

int main(){
    int M = 7;
    int binarray[M];
    int dec = getNumber();
    printf("The decimal number you entered was: %d", dec);
    *binarray = decToBin(dec, binarray, M);
    printBin(binarray, dec);
    return 0;
}

int getNumber(){
    int dec;
    printf("Enter any a number between 0 and 255: ");
    scanf("%d",&dec);
    return 0;
}

int decToBin(int dec, int binarray[], int M){
    int i, j;
    if(dec>255)
        printf("Please enter a number between 0 and 255");
    else
        for(i=7; i>=0;i--){
            j = dec >>i;
            if(j & 1){
                binarray[i] = 1; 
            }
            else {
                binarray[i] = 0; 
            } 
        }
    return *binarray;
}

void printBin(int binary[], int dec){
    int i;
    if(dec > 255){
        printf("PLese use another number");
        main(); 
    }
    else
    {
        for(i =7; i > 0;i--){
            printf("%d", binary[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You do know that outside of declarations, `*binarray` is just equivalent to `binarray[0]`, right?

Comment: The call to `main` inside the `printBin`is terriffic !!

Comment: @user3335209: my comment was somewhat ironic. See the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 2):

In your function:

```
int getNumber(){
int dec;
printf("Enter any a number between 0 and 255: ");
scanf("%d",&dec);
return 0;
}
```

You return 0, you should return dec:

```
int getNumber(){
int dec;
printf("Enter any a number between 0 and 255: ");
scanf("%d",&dec);
return dec;
}
```

Comment: +1: The function should also verify the return value of `scanf()`

Comment: Oh ok you're right thank you I really appreciate it. I did have to return dec

Answer (score 0):

In `printBin` you only prints 7 bits instead of 8 bits.

Change `for(i =7; i > 0;i--){` to `for(i = 7; i >= 0; i--){`

And in `main` change: `int M = 7;` to `int M = 8;`. You need 8 bits for the range 0..255.

`*binarray = decToBin(dec, binarray, M);` is plain wrong and not necessary, write `decToBin(dec, binarray, M) ;`. The `decToBin` function takes already care of filling the `binarray` array.

Otherwise the architecture of your program is poor:

1. The test if the input is between 0 and 255 should be in `getNumber` or
   in `main`, but not in `printBin`.
2. The call to `main()` inside the `printBin` function is completely
   wrong, even if the program works correctly.

I leave this as an exercise to the reader to find out why.